# SQL query to return only students with specific score on all tests

Tags: sql

Have a table for student test scores.

Students take multiple quizzes during a period.

Trying to develop a query that will pull only the students with 100% on **all** of the quizzes.

Table - Students
StudentId,
QuizScore

Certainly a student could receive 100% on a quiz or multiple quizzes, but just a list of the students whom scored 100% on all quizzes.

Thinking of a nested query but drawing a blank :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: WHERE quiz_score = 100

Comment: Does your table has only quiz score or quiz id also?

Answer (score 4):

```
Select studentid
From studentscores
Group by studentid
Having avg(quizscore) = 100
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, one is to compare the count of all the results to those with 100.  You can use `case` with `count` for that:

```
select studentid
from students
group by studentid
having count(case when quizscore >= 100 then 1 end) = count(*)
```

---

If quizes could have higher than 100, I've changed `=` to `>=` in the `case` statement to account for those.  Otherwise, go with @Rajesh's solution as I believe it's the easiest to check for all 100s.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an inner select to find students with at least one score that isn't 100, and then select all the StudentIDs that aren't in that set.

```
SELECT Distinct StudentID FROM Students WHERE StudentID NOT IN
(SELECT StudentID FROM Students WHERE QuizScore != 100)
```

You also want to use Distinct to get rid of multiple lines.